# how can hide Url or value of parameter in android volley?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I use `Volley` library in my app and everything is ok but when I send a request I can see the following

- Full Url of my server
- Name of parameters
- and other values.

I also check it with Ettercap tools in Kali linux and it's show me the same. My question is now is how can hide this from users?

```
String url ="http://*******.com/login";


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session

                    // Now store the user in SQLite
                    String name = jObj.getString("name");             
                    String email = jObj.getString("email");
                    String api = jObj.getString("apikey");


                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }


    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

this is the result of my debuger and Ettercap in Kali linux.

```
Email: somthings@yahoo.com Pass:somthing INFO:http://****/mypath/login CONTENT:email=somthings@yahoo.com&password=somthing&
```

Comment: Use SSL with certificate pinning.

Comment: Hide this from what users? Do users really have `ettercap`?

Comment: Do not put password on URL add it in the header or Body. Although people can still view that so you need to use SSL as Commonsware suggested.

Comment: @Enzokie He is already doing exactly that.

Comment: @Enzokie i do that but that's  not work for me.when i post the parameters i can see all parameters with their values.and i think using SSl is not my problem beacues befor connecting to server i can see this parameters and this problem is from my volley request.

Comment: Is your key-value is intend for the header or for body?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your professional advise i use SSl certificate and it is working perfectly

Answer (score -1):

I am thinking of 2 possible answers here since I am able to reproduce the issue:

1 : Use `getHeaders()` rather than `getParams()` because this is the right place for adding a header value. Check the sample below.

```
  @Override
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);

        return params;
   }
```

**NOTE:** `getHeaders()` is `public`.

2 : Using `JsonObjectRequest` rather than `StringRequest`, Why? I am guessing that you are expecting a body value rather than a header value.

```
JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
           requestBody.put("email", email);
           requestBody.put("password", password);

JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

  ... More code here

} ...
```